# Checkbox filter with li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter

My snippet:

```js
// Checkbox limit
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
// Background-color on parent change
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
  $('#filter li').removeClass('bgc');
  $(this).parent().addClass('bgc');
});
```

```css
.bgc {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filter">
  <label><li><input type="checkbox" data="rady-a-tipy" id="checkbox">Rady a tipy</input></li></label>
  <label><li><input type="checkbox" data="osobni-rozvoj" id="checkbox">Osobní rozvoj</input></li></label>
  <label><li><input type="checkbox" data="rozhovory" id="checkbox">Rozhovory</input></li></label>
</ul>
```

And then I have this code, the first jQuery part is limiting the checkboxes checking so that the user can check only one "filter" at a time. And the second part is changing the `<li>` background-color on click to show that the filter has been "chosen".

The problem is .. I need to do one more thing and that is that if I click the highlighted filter again (uncheck it) I want the class bgc to be removed from it. Right now if I click the highlighted filter again it unchecks it but the background stays there.

This is all connected to another script file that checks if any of those checkboxes are checked and queries posts based on the checked "data" value. Everything works I just need that one little thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
   $('#filter li').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('bgc');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('bgc');
});
```

Full snippet:

```js
// Checkbox limit
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
// Background-color on parent change
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
  $('#filter li').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('bgc');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('bgc');
});
```

```css
.bgc {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filter">
  <label><li><input type="checkbox" data="rady-a-tipy" id="checkbox">Rady a tipy</input></li></label>
  <label><li><input type="checkbox" data="osobni-rozvoj" id="checkbox">Osobní rozvoj</input></li></label>
  <label><li><input type="checkbox" data="rozhovory" id="checkbox">Rozhovory</input></li></label>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was super fast thank you! I can't believe this didn't came to my mind >_< thanks SO MUCH. I will mark your answer as the accepted answer once the 10 minute limit passes. Thanks a lot again!